# Diet to increase muscle mass

Tags: diet, muscle-gain, weight-gain, muscle-mass, meal-plan

I am a person who weighs 77 kilos, my height is 1.75 and I go to the gym 5 times a week and my goal is to weigh 80 kilograms, could you recommend a diet in which I can increase my muscle mass progressively and don't gain a lot of body fat.

Comment: Ah, the holy grail.  You're asking the impossible because you, like the rest of us, is an individual.  What works for one person, may not work for you.

Comment: I just want you to recommend a diet that helps me achieve my goal.

Comment: I recommend the diet laid out in the answer that I linked. Is there something missing from that, that you're looking for? High-protein, eat your veggies, water, slight caloric surplus.

Comment: thank you very much